# Compress UIImage in MonoTouch

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, uiimage, xamarin

I am in need of compressing a UIImage in MonoTouch.  I've seen several answers to UIImage compression questions.  However, all of the responses I viewed were written in Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UIImage.AsJPEG](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.AsJPEG%28System.Single%29) takes an argument to specify the amount of compression to use for the image.

```
public MonoTouch.Foundation.NSData AsJPEG (float compressionQuality)
```